# Getting Epochal Time from Date String

Tags: bash, macos, bsd

I have a process that outputs a date like this (note the padding in front of the day (4):

```
Mon Jun  4 17:53:42 2018
```

I want to get the epochal time, so I've tried:

```
echo "Mon Jun  4 17:53:42 2018" | xargs -0 date -j -f "%a %b %d %T %Y" +%s
```

This *does* work, but I am left with the annoying:

```
Warning: Ignoring 1 extraneous characters in date string (
)
```

I can live with the warning, but I've tried removing the double spacing with sed:

```
echo "Mon Jun  4 17:53:42 2018" | sed -E 's/\ +/\ /g'
```

which returns:

```
Mon Jun 4 17:53:42 2018
```

But when I try to pipe this to the date format, I get the warning again (as though `sed` is not doing its thing).

Comment: `sed` is working correctly - you told it to remove all adjacent whitespaces and it did it.

Comment: Yes, that's what I noted; but it doesn't explain why the Warning persists when the result is piped to xargs etc. Is there another extraneous character that I am missing?

Comment: I don't have `BSD` at hand but I guess `date` might have a problem with a newline automatically added by `echo`. Try replacing `echo` with `printf`.

Comment: Or if you use `bash` as you specified: `echo -n`.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is with an extraneous newline. (I should have spotted that in the Warning message.) It wasn't `echo` that was adding it - I've only used it here to show the problem. `sed` wasn't needed after all as it seems `date` will ignore extra whitespace. I've replaced it with `tr -d "\n"`

Comment: `echo` *does* add a trailing newline. Try `printf "%s" "$date"` instead. Or, remove the xargs option `-0`

Comment: The string was output from another process, I only used `echo` to show the 'incoming' string. (There must be a better way to show this, but I don't know what it is.) Clearly, the other process is also generating a newline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was not whitespace, but a newline. I removed `sed` and replaced with `tr -d "\n"` to remove the offending character:

`echo "Mon Jun  4 17:53:42 2018" | tr -d "\n" | xargs -0 date -j -f "%a %b %d %T %Y" +%s`

Comment: In my case — when processing the values of some Last-Modified HTTP response headers from `curl -I` output — I needed to do `tr -d "\r"`, to remove carriage-return characters.